# Filtering for strings containing dashes won't work

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer

I have an issue when comparing strings containing dashes `-` that I can't understand. Consider the following straightforward table:

```
// Create table
.create table Mappings (AppId:int, Namespace:string);

// Ingest some sample data
.ingest inline into table Mappings with (format="csv") <|
100,foobar
200,foo-bar
```

When I filter the table for `foobar` everything works as expected

```
Mappings 
| where Namespace == 'foobar'

> | 100 | foobar |
```

However, when filtering for `foo-bar` nothing gets returned

```
Mappings 
| where Namespace == 'foo-bar'

>
```

When using `has` instead of `==` I do get the expected result, also using `"` instead `'` doesn't make a difference.

I am confused. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I tried in Azure Data Explorer Database and it executed [successfully](https://i.imgur.com/b66YWbB.png), can you re-check once in your Azure ADX DB.

Comment: Thanks, figured it out. Pretty nasty... I'll answer my own question

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, pretty nasty one. When ingesting data inline everything is taking literally.

The following example works.

```
.create table Mappings (AppId:int, Namespace:string)

.ingest inline into table Mappings with (format="csv") <|
100,foobar
200,foo-bar

Mappings 
| where Namespace == "foo-bar"
```

And this one won't, because of the extra space in front of the string!

```
.ingest inline into table Mappings with (format="csv") <|
100, foobar
100, foo-bar

// won't return anything
Mappings 
| where Namespace == 'foo-bar'

// this will work
Mappings 
| where Namespace == ' foo-bar'
```